# Having trouble loading HTML table from XML doc

Tags: javascript, xml

I am having trouble loading values from an XML file and inserting them into a HTML table. It says that the html tag I am attempting to access  is undefined "script.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined". I am trying to insert the values of  and  into a html table from the loaded XML file.

```
// script.js

function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "table.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction() {
    var xmlDoc = XMLHttpRequest.responseXML;
    var table = '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>';
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('STUDENT');
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td><td>" +
            x[i].getElementsByTagName("AGE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
            "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById("students") = table;
}
```

```
//relevant html
<body>
    <br><br>
    <table id="students"></table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
//XML Doc Contents
<CLASS ID=”Advanced Web Development”>
    <STUDENT>
            <NAME>Tom</NAME>
            <AGE>19</AGE>
            <HEIGHT>1.3</HEIGHT>
            <SEX>M</SEX>
            <GRADE>B</GRADE>
        </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>
            <NAME>Dick</NAME>
            <AGE>29</AGE>
            <HEIGHT>1.1</HEIGHT>
            <SEX>M</SEX>
            <GRADE>A</GRADE>
        </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>
            <NAME>Harry</NAME>
            <AGE>39</AGE>
            <HEIGHT>1.5</HEIGHT>
            <SEX>M</SEX>
            <GRADE>C</GRADE>
        </STUDENT>
    <STUDENT>
            <NAME>Mary</NAME>
            <AGE>30</AGE>
            <HEIGHT>1.1</HEIGHT>
            <SEX>F</SEX>
            <GRADE>B+</GRADE>
        </STUDENT>
</CLASS>
```

Comment: **It says that the html tag I am attempting to access is undefined

Comment: that should say xml tag not html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a few things you aren't quite doing right here:

Firstly, the `XMLHttpRequest` class doesn't have a `responseXML` property: that isn't where to get the result of an asynchronous request.  Instead, the `responseXML` property belongs to the individual `XMLHttpRequest` objects (or 'instances').  You create a new `XMLHttpRequest` instance in the variable `xmlhttp` in the line `var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();`, and it will be `xmlhttp` that contains the `responseXML` property.

Additionally, you are passing the value of `this` in your `onreadystatechange` handler to `myFunction`, but `myFunction` doesn't take any arguments.  JavaScript has very lax restrictions on calling functions with the correct number of arguments: any surplus arguments are simply ignored.

Try changing the first couple of lines of this function from

```js
function myFunction() {
    var xmlDoc = XMLHttpRequest.responseXML;
```

to

```js
function myFunction(result) {
    var xmlDoc = result.responseXML;
```

This allows `myFunction` to receive the `xmlhttp` instance and pull the response XML out of it.

Secondly, at the end of the function you write:

```js
document.getElementById("students") = table;
```

Your variable `table` contains an HTML string representing the contents of a table.  However, you can't set an element to an HTML string.  What you instead want to do is to assign this HTML string to the inner HTML of this element, using the `innerHTML` property of the element:

```js
document.getElementById("students").innerHTML = table;
```

Finally, the XML document you include in your question isn't well-formed, in that the `ID` attribute of the root element uses smart quotes (`”`) to surround the value when it should use neutral quotes (`"`) instead.  If the XML isn't well-formed, the `responseXML` property of `result` will be `null`.

I made these changes to your code and it worked, in that I could load up the XML and have the table filled out with the data in the XML file.